# setting own obj key when instantiating a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I just started learning OOP in js. my question is, is it possible to dynamically set your key when you call new Function('key')? to be more clear here is my example.

```
function Rabbit(type) {
   this.type = type;
   this.name = type+"Rabbit";
}
var cage = {};
cage.addAnimal( new Rabbit('fat') );
console.log(cage)
```

this would output

```
 cage{ fatRabbit: Rabbit{
                         type: 'fat', 
                         name: 'fatRabbit',  
                         __proto__: function() {...}  
                         } 
 } //<-- Rabbit is the new Rabbit('fat')
```

If I'm doing something wrong please do tell me. thanks!

**Answer:**

instead of

```
cage.addAnimal( new Rabbit('fat') );
```

**what I did was:**

```
var cage = {};
function Rabbit(type) {
   this.type = type;
   this.name = type+"Rabbit";
   cage[this.name] = this;
}

new Rabbit('fat') // I simply call this and a new property is added on cage.
console.log(cage)
```

Comment: Its totally unclear what you're asking.

Comment: this.type = type ? something is not right. do you want the property name and its value to be same

Comment: @Jamiec please see my revised question

Comment: @Prabhu yes i want the property name the same with the name of the rabbit so that I can easily access it when calling this.name on the   constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for that:

```
function Rabbit(type) {
   this.type = type;
   this.name = type+"Rabbit";
}
var cage = {
    addAnimal: function(animal) {
        this[animal.name] = animal;
    }
};
cage.addAnimal( new Rabbit('fat') );
console.log(cage)
```

Comment: This answers the revised question much better. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your awsome answer. I updated my question. and showed how I made the result. maybe you could help me improve my answer? thanks! though im still ahving issues tho beacuse fatrabbit is called twice.

Comment: @AnthonyLloveras: Re the "what I did was" you added to your question: It's generally a very bad idea for constructor functions to have side-effects like that. Much better to either have a method on `cage` that creates and adds `Rabbit` objects, or to do it in the code where you're creating `Rabbit` (rather than the constructor).

Comment: yes Im having that problem now, tho im still having some issue. can you assist me with this? http://jsfiddle.net/v7gyvcex/4/